# How to use es6 modules import syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, es6-modules

I am using chrome v60 beta and enabled the experimental web features flag to get es6 modules support. I found that if I reference the module like this

```
    <script type="module">
        import * as jQuery from '/js/plugin/jquery.min.js';
        import * as Handlebars from "/js/plugin/handlebars.min.js";
    </script>
```

it works, but what is the point of doing it like this, and not like a regular script tag?

But mainly, I want to import from the javascript side using like

```
        import * as jQuery from '/js/plugin/jquery.min.js';
        import * as Handlebars from "/js/plugin/handlebars.min.js";
```

from from the top of a `.js` file. But the problem is if I do that, I get an error saying `unexpected token import`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Because ES6 modules aren't completely supported yet, you'd need an ES6 to ES5 transpiler for that. You have to use the module script type in order for support.

Comment: then what's the difference between module script type and just using a regular script tag to load a file?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but this is helpful: https://blog.whatwg.org/js-modules

Comment: Great question, I'm also running into this issue. For large non-module projects it is hard to start using modules because of this problem.